# How apply one class only if have other class?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a dot that haves to change when have the class active.

```
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>

.dot{
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 2em; height: 2em;
  }

.dot::before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1em; height: 1em;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: red;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

So, when my user clicks in the dot, i increment in javascript the class active, so i will have this element:

How i can apply the class `dot::before` when the dot have also the class active?

I try:

```
  .dot::before{ .active {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1em; height: 1em;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: red;
    border-radius: 100%;
    }
  }
```

Also tried:

```
  .active > .eye-dot::before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1em; height: 1em;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: red;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
```

But is not applying the `before`

Answer (score 2):

```css
.dot::before {
  content: '•';
  color: grey;
  margin-right: .5em;
}

.dot.active::before {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="dot">inactive</div>
<div class="dot active">active</div>
```